# Detect if table is specifically used as a join table for Many-To-Many relationship

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a method for my php class that will return if selected table is a table only used for many-to-many relationship.
My end goal is to be as general as possible so it works on most tables. This far I retrieve the relationships between my tables with the information_schema, so I know which tables have Foreign key in them and where they point to. But that doesn't help me to detect if said table is use only as a many-to-many relationship join table.

This is my code this far

```
public static function isManyToMany(PDO $pdo, $dbName, $table){
   try {
        $prepare = $pdo->prepare("SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL AND TABLE_NAME = ? ");
        $prepare->bindParam(1, $dbName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $prepare->bindParam(2, $table, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $prepare->execute();
        $result = $prepare->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $prepare->closeCursor();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no way for the database to know that. A user can write any query they like with any kind of join they like. There are conventions and human-understandable rules about what a "many to many relationship" is, but the database does not understand or enforce anything like that. It can define foreign key relationships, but that's as far as it goes. It has no other conceptual understanding.

Comment: That's what I feared, thanks!

Comment: If you are making an ORM: stop, it's not worth the effort.

Comment: Please remove that useless try-catch and never catch exception in this way. This is exposing information to attackers

Comment: it is only for my debuging purpose right now